# variable con tres números distintos

Tags: java

Necesito que la variable contenga dentro tres números distintos.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        a = 42;

        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Una variable puede contener solamente un valor a la vez.

Comment: Utiliza un areglo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable puede ser un array en el cual introduzcas los valores que obtienes mediante el teclado, en este ejemplo al obtener los valores en las variables a, b y c puedes crear un array que contenga los 3 valores:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce el primer numero");
    int a = scan.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Introduce el segundo numero");
    int b = scan.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Introduce el tercer numero");
    int c = scan.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Los numero introducidos son : " + a + ","+b+","+c);
    
    //Aquì agregas los numeros aun array, en la variable numeros.
    int[] numeros = {a,b,c};

    System.out.println("Los numeros almacenados en el array numeros son:");   
    //Obtiene numeros almacenados en array
    for(int n : numeros){
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias genio!!!!